# Alert text of span tag inside div with jQuery Droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

JS fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4xBx/). I have a two sets of divs, ones that can be `draggable` and some that are `droppable`.  I'm trying to add the text inside of the span element on an array so that the element that caused the drop event to be fired cannot cause a second drop to be fired (not pertinent at the moment because that doesn't work either).
Why isn't  `alert($(this).find("span").text());` finding alerting the text of the span tag inside the element that was dragged?

HTML

```
  <div id="quizContainer">

        <div id="questionsContainer">

        <div class="drugQuizzes">
            <span>DOCUSIL</span>
        </div><div class="drugQuizzes">
            <span>ORACEA</span>
        </div><div class="drugQuizzes">
            <span>ZYLOPRIM</span>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="answersContainer">


    </div>
    <div class="drugAnswers" style="background-color:PaleVioletRed;">

    </div><div class="drugAnswers" style="background-color:PaleVioletRed;">

    </div><div class="drugAnswers" style="background-color:DarkKhaki;">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the text of the dropped element, change:

```
alert($(this).find("span").text());
```

to

```
alert(ui.draggable.find('span').text());
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z4xBx/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can get dragged element span text with this:

```
ui.draggable.find("span").text()
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4xBx/2/)**

Comment: Perfect.  After messing around with all different variations of `find` and `parent` this is good to know.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the dropped element and relative properties, change:

```
alert($(this).find("span").text());
```

to:

```
alert(ui.draggable.find('span').text());
```

or generally refer the dropped element using `ui.draggable` instead of `this`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Z4xBx/3/

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop